# Remove UIView from super view after animation ended

Tags: ios

I am animating a UIView (alpha) property and I want that after the animation has finished I can remove it from the super view.

```
    -(void) hideOverlayView
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

    [topView setAlpha:0];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

One option is to use performSelector with delay option but is there a more compact way?

UPDATE 1:

Why does this code remove the view instantly?

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:topView];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

    [topView setAlpha:0];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

I should mention that first I am doing a fade-in animation and then fade-out. Above is the fade-out code which removes the UIView instantly instead of having the fade-out effect.

Comment: I had the same problem, that the view is being removed right away. I was using block and the code was inside dispatch_async. It seems like a bug. I then switched using [UIView beginAnimations like your code and it works. Though I used my own selector, not removeFromSuperview selector from the UIView class.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Straight from the [UIView docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
     animations:^{view.alpha = 0.0;}
     completion:^(BOOL finished){ [view removeFromSuperview]; }];
```

Or in your specific case:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
    animations:^{topView.alpha:0.0;}
    completion:^(BOOL finished){ [topView removeFromSuperview]; }];
```

Comment: Strangely your code also remove the UIView instantly without performing the animation. I am performing the animation on button click.

Comment: +1, Works like a charm. Careful not to remove the view from another bit of code (like the view controller that manages it) as that could ruin the animation.

Comment: Some reason the animation on a GLKView bloats (as in the vectors width increases by 5) thing. I am clearing the buffer but oh well. I decided if I am removing it from view, and under 0.15 seconds, no one will notice.

Answer (score 4):

You can use blocks to perform this kind of action ;)
Something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    topView.alpha = 1.0; topView.alpha = 0.0;
} completion:^(BOOL success) {
    if (success) {
        [topView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}];
```

Comment: For some reason the [topView removeFromSuperView] is fired instantly. I call the above from inside the method called by the button touch.

Comment: Seems weird... I use this code in my app. I initialize the view when the app launches, I created a method where I dismiss a view controller and then fire this animation and I call it when I've finished with some textFields...

Comment: I fire the button click method which fires the above code. The button is added to a UIView and that UIView is also animated.

Comment: I will post this as a separate question since it is more code that I need to add. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 4):

**Swift**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.exampleView.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
          self.exampleView.removeFromSuperview() 
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using CAKeyframeAnimation or similar you need to assign a delegate to the animation.

I created this class as the being the delegate (Swift 3):

```
class AnimationDelegate: NSObject, CAAnimationDelegate {
    typealias AnimationCallback = (() -> Void)

    let didStart: AnimationCallback?
    let didStop: AnimationCallback?

    init(didStart: AnimationCallback?, didStop: AnimationCallback?) {
        self.didStart = didStart
        self.didStop = didStop
    }

    internal func animationDidStart(_ anim: CAAnimation) {
        didStart?()
    }

    internal func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
        didStop?()
    }
}
```

Then I can use that class like this:

```
let animateView = UIView()
let anim = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
anim.delegate = AnimationDelegate(
            didStart: nil,
            didStop: {
                heart.removeFromSuperview()
        })
animateView.layer.add(anim, forKey: "animate position along path")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting `> iOS 4` then you should be looking at blocks. Otherwise look at the documentation for [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) specifically at `setAnimationDelegate:`

Answer (score 0):

If you have view which is class variable and can be recreated to fade it out and afterwards to on with new data displayed, you might need something like this:

**Swift 4**

```
func removeView(animated: Bool) {
    guard let index = subviews.index(of: viewToRemove) else { return }
    animated ? removeSubViewWithFading(from: index) :
        viewToRemove.removeFromSuperview()
}

private func removeSubViewWithFading(from index: Int) {
    let view = self.subviews[index]
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
        view.alpha = 0
    }, completion: { _ in
        if self.subviews.count > index {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    })
}
```